# Android programming copy an audio file(mp3)?

Tags: java, android, mp3, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to create copy of a mp3 file.This I need to trim that mp3 file.So using input,output stream can be used to this I guess.Can the normal text file type of copying will be able to create a file that could be played  .Someone with good knowledge of file handling in java help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MP3 file is binary file. So as long as you copy MP3 using binary file operations copy will succeed.

However to trim an MP3 file, you need to be aware of MP3 file structure. MP3 file consists of series of MP3 frames. Each frame starts with a MP3 header and followed by data. MP3 frame header contains information, using which you can find frame length.

More details on MP3 header at http://www.id3.org/mp3Frame

So as long as you copy at integral number of frames, you should be okay. Even otherwise, decoders will ignore incomplete frame.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is a solution to copy an mp3 file or everything else. I have never experienced the trimming part. However, I think it is logically possible to trim your file just by specifying the amount of buffer you need.)
Actually *dst* is the name of the copied file in the directory.

```
private void copyFile(String src, String dst) {
    FileInputStream inputStream; // create an input stream
    FileOutputStream outputStream; // create an output stream
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(src); // create object
        outputStream = openFileOutput(dst, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // save your file in private mode, which makes it inaccessible by other applications
        int bufferSize;
        byte[] bufffer = new byte[512]; // I think logically here could be useful for trimming the file. I mean just copy an specified part of the file.
        while ((bufferSize = inputStream.read(bufffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(bufffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is a suggestion about how to copy your files, which it will copy them in internal storage under your application package name. Moreover, I have not tested the trim part yet. So, I am not sure about that.

One more thing, you can get the path directory of your application by

```
getFilesDir();
```